# Openssl_pkey_get_private always returns false on development server

Tags: php, apache, openssl, digital-signature, php-openssl

I am trying to generate signature of data using my private key.

This code works on my local machine whereas `openssl_pkey_get_private` always returns false on my development server, so it fails. I get `openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key`. Is anything wrong with the server? Do I need to modify any of my server configurations?

```
class MyClass {

    protected $pub = <<< EOT

    -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

    ..Public Key....

    -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    EOT;

    protected $pri = <<<EOT

    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

    .. Private Key....


    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

    EOT;

    public function getSignature($data)
    {
        $signature = null;

        $priKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($this->pri);

        openssl_sign(iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $data), $signature, $priKey, "sha1WithRSAEncryption");

        return base64_encode( $signature );
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you copying your source from your server to the Dev server? Also, I presume the private key remains unchanged?

Comment: I transferred them using ftp.

Comment: I presume in binary mode? What happens if you go onto your development server, extract the private key and run that though OpenSSL with `openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -check`